# ArcMap not enforcing one to one relationship classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class

I'm designing a data survey application.

I created a fire hydrant feature class named `devBorne_geom`. This feature class contains only the geometry and cannot contain survey fields as I want them to be independent from the main feature class

I added a `devBorne_attrib` table containing all the attributes i need for my app. It does contain a `BorneID` field to be linked against the `devBorne_geom.GlobalID` field

I defined a relationship class between these two tables. Its defined as composite, one-to-one, with Forward notifications.

[image]

My problem is that, in arcMap(happens in arcGIS Pro too), when I'm editing `devBorne_geom` features, I'm able to add multiple `devBorne_attrib` records for a given `devBorne_geom` feature, despite having a one-to-one relationship. 
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Following J.R's suggestion, in ArcCatalog, I customized the relation like this, enforcing a 0 to 1 relation between the origin and the destination

[image]

This modification didn't prevent from adding multiple records, but ArcMap's Validate Feature tool did flagged features having more than one `devBorne_attrib`. I now have to figure out how to do it in ArcGIS Pro

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first image you can see the ''rule'' tab (next to the general tab shown), it's in this tab that you can set rules to enforce the 1-1 cardinality.

Comment: Added an edit to my post to illustrate your suggestion

Comment: if your image is your final setup, you could try to also specify the origin cardinality. (not sure it change anything but who know...)